# OpenCV GetTickCount64 error on Windows XP

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I created a simple capture from camera program in `VS2012`, `Win 7`, `OpenCV 2.4.6` and compiled it with "Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)" option. Also added "WINVER=0x0501" and "_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501" to my preprocessor option.

But still get "The procedure entry point GetTickCount64 could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll" error in Windows XP.

Please help me solve this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is only available since Windows Vista (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600). The older version of the function - GetTickCount - is available but returns ULONG value instead of ULONGLONG. This is somewhat problematic as after ~49 days it wraps around itself.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV 2.4.6 comes with 64 bits binaries so need to compile it. or you can use  prebuilt v2.3.0 or older packages in 32 bits system

Answer (score 0):

If you use runtime dynamic libaries, make sure you do use Visual Studio runtime libraries that are compatible with Windows XP/Windows 2003:

msvcr110.dll
msvcp110.dll

You should use at least version 11.0.561106.1 of those files.

You can install Visual Studio 2012 **update 4** to get them.